# Is there a Bing Static Maps API?

Tags: bing-maps, bing

I found [link text](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) for Google, but I was wondering if there was an equivalent for Bing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second link when googling for "bing static maps api"... http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vemapcontroldev/thread/678320df-06df-4fa5-b3ae-39b614f559d9

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, but might be the closest thing.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to use Bing Static Maps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701724.aspx

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

[There is one](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2012/01/jeffwilcox-maps/) created by Jeff Wilcox. Follow this blog and you'll be able to get going with static maps.